# Eager loading in "both directions"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, eager-loading

Eager loading does not work as I expect.

I have **Products** that has_many **Variants**, and of course each **Variant** belongs_to a **Product**.

I use code like this to load a product and all its variants:

```
products = Product.includes(:variants)
```

This works: all products and all variants are loaded with only two queries. However, the product of each variant is not loaded, so the following code causes another SQL-query:

```
puts products[0].variants[0].product.title
```

Why is that, and how can I fix it? I suppose `Product.includes(:variants => :product)` would work, but it causes one extra big and unnecessary SQL-query, since the Product-data is already available.

Answer (score 1):

Active Record will only eager loading an association on the level you've specified. In its point of view, `variant.product` will be treated as another level of association. So, if you want to eager loading it, you'd have to do:

```
products = Product.includes({:variants => :product})
```

Comment: That's what I wrote in the original question, but as I said that still requires an extra SQL-query.